# Inserting values randomly into an array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a method that randomly populates a 10 x 10 array of arrays, initially filled with `0`, with `1`.

```
class World

  attr_accessor :grid

  def initialize w, h, p = 0 
    @width = w 
    @height = h 
    @grid = span(@height, span(@width))
    populate(p)
  end 

  def span dim = 10, val = 0 
    out = []
    (1..dim).each do |x| 
      out.push(val)
    end 
    return out 
  end 

  def populate population
    population.times do
      puts "#{rand(@height)} #{rand(@width)}"
      @grid[rand(@height)][rand(@width)] = 1 
    end 
  end

  def show
    @grid.each do |row|
      puts row.join("")
    end 
  end 

end

world = World.new(10, 10, 5)
puts world.grid.to_s
```

I've tried several different approaches, and each time my output is something like:

```
2 4
9 3
5 6
0 8
5 6
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
0100101100
```

Why does `@grid[rand(@height)][rand(@width)]` seem to have the same keys every single iteration, despite `puts "#{rand(@height}} #{rand(@width)}"` showing changing values?

Comment: I think what you want is something like `@grid = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) { [rand(@height)][rand(@width)] } }`. That will give you an array of 10 elements, each of which is an array of 10 elements, each of those an  array `[rand(@height), rand(@width)]`.

Comment: I agree that's a better approach, but I'd really like to know why this doesn't work, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because of your span function. It works fine when you want to create the initial:

`span(@width)`

That will give you your array of:

`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

But when you call it the second time and pass in that array the push does NOT make 10 copies of that array. Instead it pushes on a reference to that array 10 times. So it doesn't matter if you do

`@grid[3][5]` or `@grid[0][5]`

They are both the same location.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the standard [`Matrix` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html):

```
require 'matrix'
m = Matrix.build(10) { rand(2) }.to_a
# => [[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: I appreciate that's a better approach, but I'd like to understand why this approach doesn't work. I think it's important to understand the "guts" of Ruby.